# How to send messages between dlls

Tags: dll, messaging

I am creating an application with the following characteristics:

- A dialog based GUI, that uses n-instances of a dll (lets call it `mainLib`).
- The `mainLib` dll, uses another dll (lets call it `commManager`) that manages TCP communication with another app.

My problem, is how to make `commManager` notify the `mainLib` about certain messages it receives.

I suppose something like `PostThreadMessage()` could be the solution, but how
do I implement it inside the dll?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, commManager runs on it's own thread. mainLib would need to create a message queue as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). When mainLib creates commManager it would have to pass its thread id to it.

If you want blocking, another option would be to use callbacks. Have mainLib pass commManager a function pointer.

Comment: isn't the PeekMessage function going to block the dll execution?  
actually both the mainLib and the commManager run in threads...  
the mainLib is doing calculations all the time and the commManager relays control messages, so i wouldn't want to block the execution...
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Line 2 of the article: "It returns without waiting for the thread to process the message."

Comment: that's in PostThreadMessage. I saw that.
My question is in receiving the message...

Comment: mainLib can call PeekMessage which is non-blocking to see if there's a message. Or it can call GetMessage which will block until a message is available.